# invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I have searched about this error and amended my query and used my order by column in aggregate function as well.
May be due to lesser knowledge of sql I am unable to catch exact meaning of this error.

I have following columns in my table:

> - [id]
> - [post_id]
> - [user_id]
> - [photo_id]
> - [photo_group_id]
> - [album_id]

my query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 MAX(share.id) as share_id, share.user_id 
FROM share  
WHERE share.post_id = 5468   
GROUP BY share.user_id 
ORDER BY share.id desc
```

I am using order by column in aggregate function already still it showing

> Column "share.id" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: You can't order by share.id because you say MAX(share.id) as share_id so you have to order by share_id instead of share.id. If this resolves it please make answered.

Answer (score 18):

The column isn't included in the ones SELECTed... I would change the ORDER BY to be either the aggregated column:

```
ORDER BY MAX(share.id) DESC
```

or the index of the column in the select:

```
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 7):

`share.id` is not valid as you used an alias in your select statement.

Try using `share_id` instead like this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 MAX(share.id) as share_id, share.user_id 
FROM share  
WHERE share.post_id = 5468  
GROUP BY share.user_id
ORDER BY share_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `ORDER BY` happens after `SELECT`. Because you only have `MAX(share.id)` in the `SELECT`, `ORDER BY` can only use what's already selected. Your 'share.id' is simply not selected for `ORDER BY` to use.
2. The other issue is you have `MAX(share.id)` and `share.user_id` on the same level. They have to be better defined by GROUP BY and aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when a certain column is not listed in group by and has nothing to do with sorting